# UNIQUE Constraint error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, syntax, migration, unique-constraint

I'm making a migration from MySQL to SQL Server 2012, but I'm running into troubles. The problem is I have several Tables with the `UNIQUE` command and I tried translating them to SQL Server syntax equivalent but when I try to make a second table with the same UNIQUE field name, this error shows up. How can I fix it.

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
There is already an object named 'Codigo' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

```
CREATE TABLE cdepartamento (
  Sys_PK int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  Sys_TimeStamp datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
  Sys_GUID varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  Sys_DTCreated datetime2(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  Sys_User varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  Sys_LastUser varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  Sys_Exported smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  Sys_DTExported datetime2(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  Sys_Info varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  Codigo varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Descripcion varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  sys_recver int DEFAULT '0',
  sys_deleted binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  sys_lock int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Sys_PK),
  **CONSTRAINT Sys_GUID UNIQUE (Sys_GUID),**
  **CONSTRAINT Codigo UNIQUE (Codigo)**
)
```

Comment: "There is already an object named 'Codigo' in the database", could you try do search in your ms SQL and make sure not "Codigo" object exit?

Comment: Guessing the index on a table cannot have a name the same as a column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error says it all...

You need to enforce uniqueness among those constraints. That's why I hate myssql and I despise those company working with it and swearing on it because one guy chose to use it.

When naming your constraint, use a widely use pattern :

```
  CONSTRAINT UN_cdepartamento_GUID UNIQUE (Sys_GUID),
  CONSTRAINT UN_cdepartamento_Codigo UNIQUE (Codigo)
```

But the best way, since you're only asking unicity on each column is to just add the constraint when defining the column. That way, you're letting your RDMBS to name it for you. And let me tell you that SQL Server and PostgreSQL do a pretty good job at naming those...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name of the Unique Constraint you are adding in Sql Server is unique. The field can be anything, but the name of the Unique constraint has to be unique in the database.